# Beginner - Create attach Contact Related List to Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, related-list

I want to capture the "Contacts" related field that exists in my "Accounts" tab, and use something similar in my "Projects" tab.  The photo below shows the contacts field in the accounts tab.

---

[image: accounts]

---

In the "Project" tab, a related list called "Contacts" does not exist when I try to customize the page.  The picture below shows that I do not have the option to use the Contacts related list on this page.

---

[image: list]

---

I need to add the Contacts field to each individual project in my "Project" tab, but it does not seem possible.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a relationship between Contacts and Projects ?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo There is a look-up relationship that exists between them to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Can you check if that is the case? If you do, perhaps is all a matter of adding the Contact related list in you Projects page layouts.

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo the relationship exists.  But As the second picture in my post shows, I am unable to find the "Accounts" available list.  How can I add this to my projects page layout?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo The "Account" list shows up in "Expanded Lookup's" rather than "Related Lists".  Can you advise?

Comment: @objectivelyC You're jumping around a bit. Your question says you wanted the contact list and now you're saying you want account? You also called a custom object a section. The issue you're having is that you're looking in the wrong spot to add the related list. View my answer below for information about page layouts.

Comment: @Toby Apologies, I meant contacts list, not account list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Section** is a Horizontal rule that separates data on a page layout. In your first screenshot "Address Information" and "System Information" are examples of a section.

In this regard, it is **not possible** to add a related list to a section on a page layout.

In your second screenshot, it shows that **Project** is a **custom object**. This is very different from a section and this distinction changes the answer drastically.

Before I tell you how to add the related list, I want to let you know that your second screenshot will **only add the related list to your own page layout and will not update the page layout of your end users.** If you need to update your page layout for end users: [Voila! How to update page layouts.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layout.htm&type=0)

Alright, now, to add the contact related list to the Project Custom object:

**Create a field on Contact**

The field type should be **Lookup**:

[image: Select Lookup]

Select **Project** in the **Related To** field:

[image: Populate Related To]

**Note:** I'm using Vehicle classification because it's a fake object I use to play around with.

Fill out the field name:

[image: Enter Field Name]

**Note:** this name cannot contain spaces and is used when the field is referenced in code. You can auto-populate the name but clicking into the Field Label field and pressing the tab key. Leave everything else on this page alone and click next.

Since you're a beginner, just keep smashing **next** until you see a **save** button. Click **save**.

And you're done. One of the pages you smash next on will automatically add the related list for you. If you're field already exists or you want to be more picky about which page layouts it gets added to, view the link I provided (there are other references available on the bottom of the page for more information about page layouts).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thank you for being so thorough.